# Jquery onclick seems to prevent checkbox checking

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I have a form like the following:

[image]

The forms id is 'filter' and I have a jquery onclick function which runs code by using the following line:

```
$(document).on('click', '#filter', function(){
    //on click do the following
```

This works perfectly. However, I have now added a checkbox to the form. The rest of the form continues to work perfectly but the checkboxes are 'uncheckable'! (if they are set to be pre-checked they stay pre-checked, if they are set to be unchecked they stay unchecked).

The only thing I can think is that the jquery on click function is overriding the checking of the checkboxes. Would this be the case? I can rectify the problem by using `blur` rather than `click` but ideally the code would run on click, and in any case id like to understand what is going on! Any ideas?

---

### EDIT

This is the contents of the click handler:

```
$(document).on('click', '#filter', function(){
    //on click do the following




        var formData = $(this).serialize(); //put the form names and values into an array called formdata
        $.get('filtertest.php',formData,processData); //jquery ajax call

        function processData(data){
            if(data==1){
            $('#content').html('<h2>There is ' + data + ' property available!</h2>');
            $('#linky').show();
            }
            else if(data==0){
            $('#content').html('<h2>There are no properties available, please expand your search options.</h2>');
            $('#linky').hide();
            }
            else{
            $('#content').html('<h2>There are ' + data + ' properties available!</h2>');
            $('#linky').show();
            }
        }//end processData

        return false; //stops the page redirect as per normal operation
        });//end submit
```

Basically the click function looks up matching details from the form in a database and returns the number of matching rows to put in the `processdata` function

Comment: Please share your markup or perhaps setup a sample on jsfiddle. Adding a checkbox to the form shouldn't be a problem unless you have some other code somewhere.

Comment: one moment, I will jsfiddle....

Comment: This [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bLTy7/) shows that the click is not the culprit. It is likely something in your click handler that is doing it.

Comment: do you have a `preventDefault` in your `click` code? This could prevent the default action (checking/unchecking the check box) to be performed.

Comment: please see edit (couldnt do a jquery to show it as the code includes an ajax call to another page....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This line is preventing the checkbox from checking:

```
return false; //stops the page redirect as per normal operation
```

Using `return false` will stop event propagation AND prevent the default behavior. The default behavior of a checkbox is to check/uncheck itself when clicked. You might be able to fix this by changing it to:

```
e.stopPropagation();
```

This should let the default behavior continue, without propagating any other events that will fire afterwards.

Or you can just take it out if it is no longer needed (based on your comment).

Comment: Im an idiot. Thats been left in there from when I had a submit button on the form. I looked and looked and looked at the code to try to fix it myself before posting on here too! :)

Comment: yea its gone! Although in future if I try to adapt the code so that it will also work for people without javascript (ie add a submit button to get the results on the page rather than automatically) would this be the way to stop the form submitting to the next page?

Comment: If you actually submit the form, then the page will still need to navigate somewhere (possibly to itself) with new data to re-render. Without JavaScript, you would have to handle it all in service side code.